# MalFormed MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query.

```
SELECT pl.id, pl.latitude, pl.longitude, pl.userId, pl.time, pl.type, com.id as com_id, com.text, com.time as com_time,
 (SELECT name as com_name, email as com_email, picture as com_picture
  FROM  aa_users 
  LEFT JOIN aa_comments ON aa_users.id = aa_comments.user_id)
usr.name as com_usr_name,
usr.email as com_usr_email,
usr.picture as com_usr_picture,
usr.type as com_usr_type FROM aa_places as pl  
LEFT JOIN aa_comments as com ON ( pl.id = com.place_id )   
LEFT JOIN aa_users as usr ON (pl.userId = usr.id)
```

The second select is failing.
What I need to do is getting 2 types of users : user owner of a place (user.name, user.email, etc..) and user owner of a comment

```
 (SELECT name as com_name, email as com_email, picture as com_picture
  FROM  aa_users 
  LEFT JOIN aa_comments ON aa_users.id = aa_comments.user_id)
```

I can't make it work. What should I change???

Comment: Do name, email, and picture exist in pl or aa_comments? you might have to specify which name you're talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner select is in the main query's select.  This is legal, but you can only return one column (and one row) when doing so -- your query is returning three columns, and likely many rows since there is no condition on it.

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but I think this should get you closer:

```
SELECT 
    pl.id, pl.latitude, pl.longitude, pl.userId, pl.time, pl.type, com.id as com_id, com.text, com.time as com_time,
    com_usr.name as com_name, com_usr.email as com_email, com_usr.picture as com_picture,
    usr.name as com_usr_name,
    usr.email as com_usr_email,
    usr.picture as com_usr_picture,
    usr.type as com_usr_type 
FROM aa_places as pl  
LEFT JOIN aa_comments as com ON ( pl.id = com.place_id )   
LEFT JOIN aa_users as com_usr ON  (com.user_id=com_usr.id)
LEFT JOIN aa_users as usr ON (pl.userId = usr.id)
```

Updated based on comment.

Comment: This is what I want. The thing is in the table aa_comments, there is only the field user_id. 
So com2.name as com_name, com2.email as com_email, com2.picture, do not exist

Comment: So, `places.userid=aa_users.id` gives you the place owner, `places.id=aa_comments.place_id` gives you place comments, and `aa_comments.user_id=aa_users.id` gives you the comment owner?  I will update my answer.